# PHP: Connect to a MS SQL Server with Dynamic Port Allocation

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to browse a customer's Microsoft SQL server database with PHP but port 1433 is closed. Digging around I found out MSSQL can run in **Dynamic Port Allocation** mode, that means it will choose a random listen port at first execution, and will likely remain the same accross startup. I know I can find out the current port, but since *likely* is not *always* and I'd like to avoid searching for it again, is there any way to remotely discover the port to connect to?

From what I could understand by my searches this job is usually accomplished by SQLBrowser(.exe ?), but how to do this on Linux?

### Update on the solution

While @Chris' answer was correct I was missing a simple but essential bit: on every change of odbc.ini you need to run:

```
odbcinst -i -s -f /etc/odbc.ini
```

to update system's DSN.
After that I could connect using

```
isql -v DSN_NAME username password
```

### Troubleshooting

To check server instance:

```
tsql -H HOSTNAME_OR_IP -L
```

this will print server information, including instance names and port to which you should be able to connect using standard telnet or mssql client.

Comment: Probably one of those "security features" by MS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your answer was correct, I had to do minor changes to make it work. I decided to write them here. Steps are basically the same. On Ubuntu/Debian:

```
apt-get install php5-sybase unixodbc tdsodbc
```

Edit `/etc/odbcinst.ini` and add driver details

```
[TDS]
Description = FreeTDS Driver
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
```

Edit `/etc/odbc.ini` and enter connection details

```
[SQLSRV01]
Description = SQL Server test
Driver = TDS
Trace = No
Server = SERVER_IP\INSTANCE_NAME
TDS_Version = 9.0
#Database = DataBaseName
#ReadOnly = Yes
```

The last two parameters are optional. *Driver* must match what we wrote in odbcinst.ini. The *Server* directive **must** be in that syntax (of course *SERVER_IP* can be an hostname too).

According to UnixODBC the next step should not be necessary, but this is what made my installation work. Run the following command (every time odbc.ini is changed)

```
odbcinst -i -s -f /etc/odbc.ini
```

After this you should be able to connect using:

```
isql -v SQLSRV01 nome_utente password
```

Or via PHP:

```
$db = new PDO("dblib:host=SQLSRV01;dbname=DBNAME","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

ODBC drivers know to contact SQL server on port 1434 to find which dynamic port is associated with a named instance. user `SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME` to connect.

Long answer:

I started [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47651/when-is-a-dynamic-port-dynamic) which led [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823938) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/265808).

Eventually I found [this](http://lucasmanual.com/mywiki/unixODBC):

> If you are using mssql with multiple instances and dynamic port
>   allocation you can use the following:
>
> ```
> [SQLServer2008]
> Description     = Production Server
> Driver          = TDS
> Trace           = No
> Server          = servername\instance_name
> TDS_Version     = 8.0
> ```

Which seems to be echoed in a similar [IBM Doc](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21460326):

> **Question**
>
> SQLServer is setup to dynamically assign ports. In the .odbc.ini file,
>   the Address parameter is usually set to hostname colon port number
>   (Address=HostName:1433), but the port may change. How should we handle
>   this?
>
> **Answer**
>
> For the Address parameter value, instead of entering the hostname
>   colon port, enter the hostname a backslash and the server instance
>   name.
>
> For example, in Unix/Linux, use the IBM SQLServer Wire Protocol driver
>   and enter the following in the .odbc.ini file in the DSN definition
>   for the connection to the SQLServer data source:
>
> Address=HostName\Server_Instance_Name
>
> For Windows, use the ODBC Data Sources Administrator to configure a
>   System DSN for the data source using the IBM SQLServer Wire Protocol
>   driver.
>
> Note: The parameter is Server

Comment: thanks, I found most of the link you posted already, but had issues in configuring UnixODBC. Basically, the solution provided by lucasmanual.com doesn't work to me. I have a Windows PC (in the domain) with ODBC configured and working for that MSSQL server, but I cannot replicate it on linux. I don't know if it's then a domain issue, because I cannot resolve the hostname used in Odbc. But I tried with IPADDRESS\Instancename and doesn't work anyway...